# Alias enum values in schema.yml

Tags: php, symfony1, alias

Can anyone tell me if there's any way to add an alias to a value of a enum fixture type?

Something like this:

```
responsabilityType:
  values:
    - ~
    - StepAnaliseCC as Credit Responsability
  notnull: false
```

Comment: Wait, is this in a fixture file or a schema file?

Answer (score 1):

Enum is a MySQL specific type, you cannot have a column of type enum in your schema.yml as it is database-independent.  You can easily change the model name by adding an _attribute in schema.yml like so:

```
StepAnaliseCC: 
    _attributes: { phpName: CreditResponsability }
```